# In Django how to display username upon successful login

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am using the django `User model` to store user's information. Now after login I want to redirect the user to the dashboard where a message should be delayed: Welcome <his_first_name>. I tried the following code:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {"name": user.first_name})
```

but I am getting the following error: `name 'user' is not defined`. **What am I missing?**

my register function looks something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        firstname = request.POST['firstname']
        lastname = request.POST['lastname']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, username=username, password=password)
        user.save()
        return redirect('login')
```

In the above code, what I understand is that `user` is an object of the `User` class, then how can all objects have the same name user, **what am I misunderstanding?**

**Edit:**
thanks to the answers below, I missed the request keyword before user.first_name, it should have been:

```
return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {"name": request.user.first_name})
```

Comment: well where is your ```user``` coming from in your code snipped??? did you mean to use ```request.user```? ```User``` is the class/Model while ```user``` is a variable.

Comment: yes but I am not sure how to call the `user` inside the dashboard function

Comment: The user should be attached to your ```request```after successfull authentication

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get user from request

```
request.user
```

and use in your function.

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {"name": request.user.first_name})
```

Safe way to get user's first name:

```
request.user.get_short_name()
```

Also you can get full name using:

```
request.user.get_full_name()
```

Comment: what is the difference between `request.user.first_name` and `request.user.get_short_name()`?

Comment: Basically first_name is direct attribute of user and get_short_name() is function that return user's first name. so its safe to use get_short_name() in case of in future you want to change something you can override this method and no need to change uses at every place.

Comment: ohh nice, one more doubt what I understand is `user` is an object of the `User` class, then how can all objects have the same name `user`, what am I misunderstanding? or is it like all the objects have the same name but different Ids?

Comment: Because user is the name of the object and it can be anything. but when the user is authenticated, django inject the current user in the request with name user and we can access using request.user

Comment: @yogeshiitm you need to understand the underlying concepts of programming and what a variable is, an object, class, etc.. To keep it brief and very general, imagine your user database (memory), each user has a unique ID (memory address) a variable points at the ID (or memory address) of that specific user (object in memory). It's like one time you point it at ID 1, the next time to some other ID 7331

Answer (score 0):

`User` is the class name already defined in django. `user` is a variable name that you didn't define at all.

The line

```
user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=firstname, last_name=lastname, username=username, password=password)
```

creates a variable in `register` method scope. No other method can see it. You need to take a **Python** tutorial before trying django